# Children's book(s) with animal stories

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to find a children's book(s) that I read as a kid. I read it around 1991-2000 so it could only be sooner than that, no later. I am saying books because they might be 2, although I think it was just 1.

All the characters in the books were animals that could talk and there were different stories about each one of them.

I think the cover, when you open both sides would be the whole jungle with a pond(or lake) in the middle where some would fish, other would just climb the trees and other animals would just sit nearby.

I also recall that one of the stories was about an aligator that was a dentist.

And one of the stories, maybe the last, was a christmas(?) story about mice that were living to a snowy village with a bridge and lanterns and at some point one mouse was carrying something with a sledge.

In case there are 2 books, then the story about the mice would be the 2nd one.

Anyone seen/read any of these?

Thanks

```
Edit to add more info:
```

To the best of my recollection,
 1. They are picture books with 1 page of an image and the other page with a story relevant to the image.
 2. I would say they are anthropomorphic since I remember the dentist wearing a uniform and using tools.
 3. The age would be 4-8 I guess, I don't remember when kids start to read xd
 4. During my search I couldn't get samples of books that I found so I didn't dismiss any (that seemed relevant).

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about the book(s)? Are they picture books with limited text and illustrations on every page or are they books of short stories, short books with one story each? What sort of age group are they aimed at? Are the animals fully anthropomorphic, ie does the dentist alligator have a clinic and apparatus, or does he have plover birds to do the tooth-cleaning? Are there titles you have already dismissed as not being the correct ones, what search terms have you used when looking for the book? Any information you can give helps.